# What is the legal basis that can prevent a carton being reused in Australia

Tags: australia

I came across a box that has the words "Reuse of this carton is prohibited and is punishable by law"

With that box in mind, I have a few questions

- Is this true are there laws that could enforce prevention of reuse
- If so what is the basis
- Does it apply to commercial and non-commercial uses? e.g. Could it be around the packing of strawberries
- Does this mean it is ok to bin the carton but not reuse it?

[image: Larger picture of box]

[image: Smaller picture of box]

Answer (score 2):

The law is called “That’s my carton, get your hands off it.”

That particular carton *belongs* to Visy and they have rented it to someone else on the terms that it be returned to them when that person is finished with it and not be reused.

If you take someone’s property without permission that is the crime of theft and the tort of conversion- the first is punishable by the state and the second allows the owner to seek damages.

Comment: From what I've seen these boxes tend to get binned/recycled. what would be a likely motivation.

Comment: @user1605665 that's good for Visy too - binned boxes do not destroy the market like reused boxes do